# What formula does prop.test use?

Tags: r

The `prop.test` function apparently doesn't use the formula given [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/48) to create a confidence interval, so what formula is being used? Below is a confidence interval `CI` computed with prop.test and a confidence interval `CI.2` computed using the formula given [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/48).

```
CI <- prop.test(5,10)$conf.int

se.hat <- 0.5/sqrt(10)
z <- qnorm(0.975)
CI.2 <- 0.5 + c(-1,1)*z*se.hat

CI
CI.2 # not the same
```

Comment: If you type `prop.test` in the console, you can see the code for the function and probably figure out exactly what it's doing. Also, if you want access to a wide range of binomial tests, see the `binom.confint` function in the `binom` package ([this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/207809/3162) has an example). The formula you linked to is the asymptotic test.

Comment: I believe it's the [Wilson score test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) intervals

Comment: That's suggested by the first reference in `?prop.test`: *Wilson, E.B. (1927) Probable inference, the law of succession, and statistical inference*

Comment: Looking at the formula given for  Wilson score test intervals on wikipedia and comparing to the source code for `prop.test`, it appears the interval produced is the Wilson score interval with a continuity correction, which is equivalent to the Yates' chi-squared test. Thanks

Comment: @JimSlonder Now that you've verified, feel free to post that as an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses the [Wilson score interval with continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval_with_continuity_correction), i.e. the Yates chi-squared test.

Answer (score 2):

We can confirm Ryan's answer comparing the results from `IC.wc` and `prop.test` using the example given below:

```
IC.wc <- function(x, n, conf.level=0.95){
  p <- x/n ; q <- 1-p
  alpha <- 1- conf.level
  z <- qnorm(p=alpha/2, lower.tail=F)
  const1 <- z * sqrt(z^2 - 2 - 1/n + 4*p*(n*q+1)) 
  const2 <- z * sqrt(z^2 + 2 - 1/n + 4*p*(n*q-1)) 
  L <- (2*n*p + z^2 - 1 - const1) / (2*(n+z^2))
  U <- (2*n*p + z^2 + 1 + const2) / (2*(n+z^2))
  c(L, U)
}

IC.wc(x=35, n=50)
prop.test(x=35, n=50, correct=TRUE)$conf.int
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to get a CI exactly the same as by formula:

```
library(BSDA) 
x=35
n=50
phat=x/n
xvar=c(rep(1,x),rep(0,n-x))## replicate the original variable!
s=sqrt(phat*(1-phat))
z.test(xvar,sigma.x=s)
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this is **not** an answer to the OP's question. The OP wants to know what formula `prop.test()` uses.  Your answer shows how to get confidence intervals based on a Gaussian approximation (which is quite different, and generally worse - its only real advantage is simplicity).

Comment: thanks for your comments. I really appreciate it. I wonder how you got the "generally worse" conclusion? Could you refer to any paper or book for that conclusion?

Comment: Here you go: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1 (refs to various textbooks)

Answer (score 0):

For single proportion - it's the Wilson score test.
For 2 proportions - it's the Rao score test, but the CI are Wald's

You can find more details in [this question I asked on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608955/why-is-the-confidence-interval-for-difference-in-two-proportions-inconsistent-wi)