# the p value and confidence interval in `prop.test() in R`

Tags: r, stat

I wonder how the confidence interval by formula and from `prop.test ()` are different:

They should be the same except for some rounding errors. But the discrepancy is so big. I wonder if there is any reasons behind. thanks a lot!

```
n=52
x=21
phat=x/n
phat
## by formula
n*phat
n*(1-phat)
# so condition is met
#95%CI
me=qnorm(.975)*sqrt(phat*(1-phat)/n)
lb=phat-me
lb
ub=phat+me
ub
## p value
p0=.5
z=(phat-p0)/sqrt(p0*(1-p0)/n)
z
pvalue=2*pnorm(-abs(z))
pvalue
##by prop.test
prop.test(x,n,0.5,correct =FALSE)
prop.test(x,n,0.5)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580829/what-formula-does-prop-test-use

Comment: I figure out a way to get a CI exactly the same as by formula:

```
library(BSDA) 
x=35
n=50
phat=x/n
xvar=c(rep(1,x),rep(0,n-x))## replicate the original variable!
s=sqrt(phat*(1-phat))
z.test(xvar,sigma.x=s)
```